# GPIO/PCIe programing

Tags: gpio, pcie

I want to connect a PCIe 16x 3.0 GPU card to a Raspberry pi. I don't mind lo loose bandwidth, i just want to use the core GPU capabilities. So, the only idea that came out to my mind is to use the 26 GPIO RPi pins. I am concern about the GPIO/PCIe programing, do not have any idea neither an approach. Is this a crazy a idea ? can somebody help me to get a big picture of what i must to do ?

Comment: It is a crazy idea indeed. Study the PCI-Express protocol. After mastering it, you will be able to come up with specific questions.

Comment: Yes, it's a crazy idea. Actually, there's no point in doing this. The extra circuitry needed to interface that PCIe GPU to your Raspberry Pi would be quite complex and would cost more than replacing your Raspberry Pi with something having native PCIe connectivity.

Comment: @LaszloValko i thought the same but i did not find a board with native PCIe connectivity.

Comment: Maybe that's because you were not looking at the right places. http://compulab.co.il/products/sbcs/sbc-a510/ http://www.globalscaletechnologies.com/t-openrdudetails.aspx

Comment: I am planning to use MCS9990 (PCIe to 4-Port USB 2.0 Host Controller) to make a board that connects the GT640 PCI 3.0 16x with the RPi USB 2.0. I think the only difficulty is the driver of that chip but i have time to develop it. If i implement this, what about the other software, (CUDA and GForce driver) they work on top of the board driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet would probably be to check whether a [PLX PCIe bridge](http://www.plxtech.com/products/expresslane/bridges) would be usable for this purpose.

It's highly likely that abandoning this idea of using a Raspberry Pi and instead using something that has a PCIe port built in instead will be vastly easier and cheaper.

Comment: I think this is my solution. The problem is the supply power of the GPU. Do i will have problems with an external ATX power supply?

Comment: Maybe i can use a Raspberry Pi and the PLX PCIe bridge. As i said, i am not concern about transmision rates.

Comment: @ArturoVeras I have to remind you that I did not check that the bridges work in the way you want to use them. They certainly work as PCIe devices so you can use them to connect your devices with some simple generic local bus into a PC. I don't know if they work the other way around, I haven't inspected the manuals in detail.

Comment: I was talking to PLX Company and, as you said, it works with some simple generic local bus, if you want some specific device you have to develope your own software. Not an easy solution but is posible.

Answer (score 2):

The GPIO pins on the Raspberry Pi are not even close to being fast enough (maybe a couple of MHz vs several GHz required for PCI-E). You can however, check this out: http://hackaday.com/2012/10/08/stm32-driving-a-pcie-video-card/

This doesn't use the PCI-Express interface at all, but some Radeon GPUs have a 'debug bus' which can be used to write internal registers at low speeds, apparently through I2C, which the Raspberry Pi can interface to. It looks like the code got taken offline (probably NDA stuff, or the original author is trying to make a business out of it). If you had a couple of months to spare and experience with hacking Linux drivers, you can probably replicate his work by looking at the open source Linux drivers.

Comment: Fast enough to transfer the data or fast enough to comply with the protocol?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to hit the problem the hard way, you can bit bang the protocol with some external help.

There are several signals you need to mind: signals shared by all cards `SM_SCL`, `SM_SDA`, `PCIE_IRQ` and `PCIE_CLK`, as well as per-channel `PCIE_Rx` and `PCIE_Tx`.

Most PCI-E lines are differential signaling which should be derived externally to and from single-ended signal from your Pi. This includes all `PCIE_*` lines except IRQ. `SM_*` are SMBus which can go directly to the I2C of the Pi, and all other signals will need to be bit banged (despite with limited external hardware support).

You do not need to implement a full x16 bus, a x4 bus (uses 10 GPIOs and I2C) will be enough, if your GPU can work at that painfully slow speed.

Answer (score 1):

A few sites have tested the Pi's gpio speed and a quick search shows speeds on the order of hundreds of KHz. Not sure of the PCI 3 frequency off the top of my head but I believe each data line runs in the MHz range.

The low frequency of the GPIO coupled with the coding overhead for each pin it would be impossible to bit bang the Pi fast enough.

Comment: "Not sure of the PCI 3 frequency off the top of my head but I believe each data line runs in the MHz range." They actually run in the GHz range...

Comment: So, at last GPIO solution is not feasible at all.

Answer (score 0):

If the Raspberry Pi has PCIe, then it is not exposed in a slot and it would require board modification which would be almost impossible for all but a very select few individuals without destroying it. Try the "lspci -vnnt" command and see if any devices are present. If PCIe is present, it is likely only there for the onboard Wi-Fi (much like things like the Galaxy S8).

The new RockPi 4 has the same mounting holes and form factor as the Raspberry Pi. It has the same compatible GPIO 40-pin header. It has a PCIe 2.0 x2 M.2 slot. You can adapt that to a full-sized PCIe slot. It will be bandwidth limited, but it should work. If you are gaming, then results might be poor. But for compute tasks that do not need much CPU-GPU communication, it should work great.

https://shop.allnetchina.cn/collections/frontpage/products/rock-pi-4-model-b-board-only-with-dualband-2-4-5ghz-wlan-bluetooth-5-0

You need to make sure that the slot has a PSU connector to supply 75W to the slot, and you might need extra PSU connectors straight to the graphics card if it is power hungry. You have to be careful because some slots create 3.3V from other voltages instead of from a SATA power connector, and if it is not designed for a GPU, it might overload and break. You either need one that is designed for a GPU, or one that takes the power directly from SATA power (not Molex, and SATA power that connects to the SFF-8643 connector does not guarantee anything, as some cables have Molex instead).

The Hikey 960 is the same deal but has incompatible mounting with the Raspberry Pi.

Something here might help: https://click.intel.com/desktop-system-parts.html

Those can go from M.2 to SFF-8639 and from there you might be able to get a SFF-8639 to PCIe slot adapter from Amazon or similar. I have seen whole kits from M.2 to PCIe but cannot vouch for their performance or reliability. Plus, some of them only wire one lane of PCIe from the M.2 slot. Make sure you get the 4-lane ones.